# backbone js print variable value in view which is an html

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am very new to backbone.js and learning it. I managed to pass my variables to the view and they are being displayed fine. What I am struggling with is what if the variable being passed to the view is an `html` that looks like this
`<p>I am an html print me on view</p>` now suppose this variable is called `description` so inside the view if I do

```
<%-description %>
```

This actually displays the result in html as you can see in the following screenshot. So my question is how can i print a variable on view which is an html?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) doc, it says

> Template functions can both interpolate values, using `<%= … %>` [...]  If you wish to interpolate a value, and have it be HTML-escaped, use `<%- … %>`

Use `<%= description %>` to insert the raw, unescaped HTML.